# On the question "What is the c# internal for VB.Net"

Tags: discussion, old-answers

I have to get my hands dirty with some Vb.Net code this morning and forgot to what the `internal` keyword was. No problem, we'll just google it: "internal vb.net keyword" please google.

First result is this SO question:

[What is C# 'internal' in VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395753/what-is-c-sharp-internal-in-vb-net)

Accepted answer is great and has a link to more info perfect... however there is all of this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395846/426894](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2395846/revisions)

> its not hard to find. a simple googling show you the equevalent and
>   that's
>
> Friend

A voice of reason though:

> I'm sorry but this is the first link in my search result and the link you posted does not work

My question is this:

Should I flag answers and comments like this on older questions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to flag the answer because besides the unnecessary text (*chaos*) the actual answer to the question is right there. Instead of flagging and increasing the amount of moderation required it's probably more common sense and sensible to just edit/improve the answer and remove the noise.

Regarding the comments - if there already is an accepted answer and the comments don't add any value to the question/answer feel free to flag them as obsolete/non-constructive or even too-chatty and use common sense when selecting the reason for flagging. If you feel they are somehow offensive flag as such. If none of the current reasons fit and you still believe this comment should be removed use a custom reason **as a last resource** and explain why the comment should be removed.

*Out of pure courtesy I have edited the answer to be more up to the standards. Please note that telling someone that something is easy to google is not constructive throughout SE Network.

Comment: The changes make the answer redundant to the accepted answer and another non-accepted answer. Is that a problem? (Of course, it was pretty redundant to begin with, I suppose.)

Comment: @jpmc26 FYI, I have flagged an answer with a custom reason asking for deletion as it had no votes, was posted 2 years after the question was asked and another answer was already accepted, added nothing new nor valuable to the current Q&A but a moderator rejected the flag...

Comment: FYI, I flagged the question, being more verbose, to delete the answers that just regurgitate the same things, and only that answer was deleted :/

Comment: @Braiam oh wow. the answer that was posted in 2010 was deleted but [the one from 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9528299/2140173) is still there... it even got 2 upvotes since the last time I checked... hm...